# Google Charts: Loop through control (to set different states) and print PNG for each state

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a single Google Chart with a control. The control is a category filter (one category max) that lets me select which company whose data I want to see. I want to create a function that loops through each company and obtains the PNG for each.

My function only prints the last company's PNG with the loop. I've looked into callbacks and closures but am still struggling to grasp the concept entirely.

Code snippet:

```
//chart is a ChartWrapper
//companyIdFilter is a ControlWrapper

$(function() { 
  $("#loopSave").click(function() {        
      var arrCompanyID = [1,2,3];

      for (var i=0; i<arrCompanyID.length; i++) {
        var currentID = arrCompanyID[i];        
        (function(id){          
              google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart.getChart(), 'ready', function(){                       
                var initState = { selectedValues: [id] };
                companyIdFilter.setState(initState);        

                var chartImg = chart.getChart().getImageURI();
                sendChartToDrive_Src(chartImg, id);
             });              

            companyIdFilter.draw();
        })(currentID);

      }
  })
});
```

**Edit**

What I am trying to accomplish is a loop that goes through each company ID and saves + upload the image to Google Drive. My data table is structured to match the source data in Google Sheets. What's happening right now for me is that my function will only save the *last* chart (in this case, 2). I am following this [blog post](https://decembersoft.com/posts/understanding-javascript-closures-in-for-loops/) and it seems like there is a similar issue.

Partial jsfiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonology/b90cvsnf/12/](https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonology/b90cvsnf/11/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than depending on the filter's state to change the chart,
recommend setting a view on the chart to only draw the rows for a specific company

you can use data table method --> `getFilteredRows`
this will return an array of row indexes for a given column value

```
  chart.setView({
    // exclude company id column from chart (column 0)
    columns: [1, 2],

    // include rows for company id
    rows: data.getFilteredRows([{
      column: 0,
      value: id
    }])
  });
```

not sure exactly how your code is setup, using a dashboard, etc.
but following is working snippet to illustrate the concept
each image is added to the page for example purposes
click "save image" to see it in action...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'id');
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');
  data.addRows([
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 2, 2],
    [1, 3, 3],
    [2, 21, 1],
    [2, 22, 2],
    [2, 23, 3],
    [3, 41, 1],
    [3, 42, 2],
    [3, 43, 3]
  ]);

  var companyIdFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'control_div',
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'id',
      ui: {
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false
      }
    }
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    view: {
      columns: [1, 2]
    }
  });

  var dashboardContainer = document.getElementById('dashboard_div');
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(dashboardContainer);
  dashboard.bind(companyIdFilter, chart);
  dashboard.draw(data);

  var colors = ['cyan', 'magenta', 'lime'];  // for example only

  $('.save-button').on('click', function () {
    var arrCompanyID = data.getDistinctValues(0);

    $.each(arrCompanyID, function (i, id) {
      chart.setView({
        // exclude company id column from chart (column 0)
        columns: [1, 2],

        // include rows for company id
        rows: data.getFilteredRows([{
          column: 0,
          value: id
        }])
      });

      // for example only
      chart.setOption('backgroundColor', colors[i]);
      chart.setOption('colors', ['yellow']);

      google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart.getChart(), 'ready', function(){
        var chartImg = chart.getChart().getImageURI();

        // for example only
        $('#image_div').append('<img src="' + chartImg + '" />');

        //sendChartToDrive_Src(chartImg, id);
      });

      chart.draw();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.control {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <div>
    <button class="save-button ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all">
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span><span>&nbsp;Save Image</span>
    </button>
    <div class="control" id="control_div"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
<div id="image_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks WhiteHat! Here's a jsfiddle of what I'm trying to accomplish: https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonology/b90cvsnf/12/. The way my data table is structured is different and do you think it's fundamentally flawed for what I'm trying to achieve? (a loop that saves an image for each category 'state'). I still need some more time to look at what you've provided and will comment on that soon.

Comment: looks ok to me, just recommend using a view on the chart wrapper, rather than depending on the filter's state -- the answer above should get you there (it works just like jsfiddle), let me know if you need more help...

Comment: This works as intended with my code, thank you @WhiteHat. Just a few questions to confirm my understanding: (1) Why is it better to use a view on the chart wrapper as opposed to a filter's state? (2) Is it even possible using the filter's state? I am curious to see how this would work with closures and callbacks - it's quite an ambitious javascript topic for me and I would love to see it in action.